# Python Beautifulsoup lxml parsing crops tag name at 100 chars

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, lxml

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(xml_file), features="lxml")
tag_list = soup.find_all(recursive=False)
for tag in tag_list:
  print(tag.name)
```

xml

```
<us-gaap:CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalentsPeriodIncreaseDecreaseIncludingExchangeRateEffect contextRef="Duration_4_1_2016_To_3_31_2017" unitRef="Unit1" decimals="-3">2999000</us-gaap:CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalentsPeriodIncreaseDecreaseIncludingExchangeRateEffect>
```

prints

```
us-gaap:CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalentsPeriodIncreaseDecreaseIncluding
```

Is there a limit on tag name that bsoup4 can process?

How to get the whole tag name in this case from the xml

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(xml_file), features="lxml")
tag_list = soup.find_all()
for tag in tag_list:
   try:
       print(tag["name"])
   except:
       pass
```